# Side Scrolling with navbar

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I will show you with this example:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/adsKXLw.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-size: 1050px 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#huge {
  width: 900px;
  height: 498px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 103, 48, 0.5);
  left: 75px;
  top: 0%;
}

.navbar div, .navbar div p {
  position: fixed;
}

#navbar-background {
  width: 820px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 115px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  z-index: 1
}

#home-div {
  background-color: rgb(249, 162, 100);
  width: 210px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 135px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-left: 1px solid white
}

#home-div-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 131, 78);
  width: 215px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
  left: 140px;
  position: fixed;
}

#home-text {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
  left: 145px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}



#clan-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 505px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#clan-text {
  left: 512px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#clan-div-2 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 597px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#clan-text-2 {
  left: 610px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#games-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 712px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#games-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 35px;
  left: 723px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Own Clan Website</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css">
    <link href="script-1.js" type="text/javascript"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div div="everything">
      <div id="huge"></div>
      <div class="navbar">

        <div id="navbar-background"></div>

        <div id="home-div">
          <p id="home-text">Home Thing</p>
        </div>

        <div id="home-div-button"></div>

        <div id="clan-div">
          <p id="clan-text">Thing<br>Button</p>
        </div>

        <div id="clan-div-2">
          <p id="clan-text-2">Hello <br>World</p>
        </div>

        <div id="games-div">
          <p id="games-text">Stuff</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The navbar is set to fixed so that the it will stay when the user scrolls down or up. The problem is that if the user's screen is small then when they scroll sideways the navbar will stay with them.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/adsKXLw.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-size: 1050px 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#huge {
  width: 900px;
  height: 498px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 103, 48, 0.5);
  left: 75px;
  top: 0%;
}

.navbar div, .navbar div p {
  position: fixed;
}

#navbar-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  top: 11px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#home-div {
  background-color: rgb(249, 162, 100);
  width: 40%;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#home-div-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 131, 78);
  width: 40%;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 8px;
  top: 40px;
  
}

#home-text {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#clan-div {
  width: 16%;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 250px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#clan-text {
  left: 275px;
  width: 9%;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#clan-div-2 {
  width: 15%;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 342px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#clan-text-2 {
  left: 365px;
  top: 35px;
  width: 9%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#games-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 445px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#hello {
width: 100%;
}

#games-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 35px;
  left: 468px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Own Clan Website</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css">
    <link href="script-1.js" type="text/javascript"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div div="everything">
      <div id="huge"></div>
      <div class="navbar">

        <div id="navbar-background">

        <div id="home-div">
          <p id="home-text">Home Thing</p>
        </div>

        <div id="home-div-button"></div>

        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

See if this helps, you should look into Bootstrap or Foundation as well.